# Share internet connection in OSX through existing wireless network?

Tags: macos, networking, internet, nat

It's easy to share your Internet with AirPort by checking "Internet Sharing" in the system preferences, but this option asumes you want to create a new wireless network.
Is there an easy way to configure Internet sharing if you want to use an already existing network?

I want my laptop to use the existing wireless AP and share its internet to other clients within this network.
Tried manually running `natd -interface ppp0` without luck

Answer (score 3):

Got it working

For anyone interested, these were the steps:

1. sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
2. natd -interface ppp0 -dynamic
3. ipfw add divert natd all from any to any via ppp0